# SQL query to find the last day of a particular formatted month - YYYY/MM

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I have months in the following format -

```
2022  /  12
2021  /  03
2020  /  02

YYYY  /  MM
```

I want to find out the last day of these months. i.e. 2022/12/31, 2021/03/31 , 2020/02/28

I am using the below code -

```
to_date(to_char(:p_month||'01/', 'yyyy / mm/dd'), 'yyyymmdd')
```

but it is throwing an invalid format error.

Comment: 30 days have September, April. June. and November. All the rest have 31 days excepting February which is 28 days long and 29 days in a leap year.  You could probably use that as part of the solution.

Another way would be to take the first day of the month following as a date and substract one day.

Comment: Why should he do such crazy things instead of just using the LAST_DAY function?

Comment: I think you have `to_date` and `to_char` switched around. Then as @JonasMetzler says, `last_day` gives you the last day of the month that a date falls in, so you don't need any `dd`.

Answer (score 1):

There are following steps you need to take in order to get your desired result:

1. Remove the whitespaces within your string
2. Cast your string to a date
3. Select the last day of the month for this date.

There is likely more than one way to do this. As example you can do following:

1st part: `SELECT REPLACE(datepart,' ','') FROM yourtable;` to remove whitespaces...

2nd part: `SELECT TO_DATE(REPLACE(datepart,' ',''),'YYYY/MM') FROM yourtable;` to cast your column as date and...

3rd part: `SELECT LAST_DAY (TO_DATE(REPLACE(datepart,' ',''),'YYYY/MM')) FROM yourtable;` to get the last day of the month for this date.

Please see the working example here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=48d6e9c773367628e05c65de8ca72e70)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert the input string to a date - so the first function you apply should be `to_date` (you have the two conversions in the wrong order in your attempt). Oracle is tolerant of unneeded spaces in the input string; and `to_date` accepts incomplete formats, supplying defaults for the missing components.

So, `to_date(:p_month, 'yyyy/mm')` will return the first day of the month (that's the default: `dd = 1`, as well as `hh24:mi:ss = 00:00:00`).

Then you can apply `last_day` to this result, and if needed, convert back to a string using `to_char`. Like this:

```
    to_char(last_day(to_date(:p_month, 'yyyy/mm')), 'yyyymmdd')
```

Testing it:

```
variable p_month varchar2(10)
exec :p_month := '2022 / 03'

select :p_month as mth,
       to_char(last_day(to_date(:p_month, 'yyyy/mm')), 'yyyymmdd') as last_day
from   dual;

MTH        LAST_DAY
---------- --------
2022 / 03  20220331
```

By the way, the specific error you got was because you put the concatenated slash in the wrong place. You concatenated `01/` instead of `/01`, so your string became `2022 / 1201/` instead of `2022 / 12/01`. Oracle tolerates unnecessary spaces, but it can't work with delimiters in the wrong place.